# LLVM IR main function returning void

Tags: llvm, void

I'm testing a main function that simply returns void and am get core dump errors (signal 65 or 73) when running the bitcode with `lli`:

```
define void @main() {
entry:
  ret void
}
```

Is it a limitation of `lli` or just plain illegal in LLVM?

I'm well aware that in C++ the declaration of a main function with a return type of void is incorrect. In fact I've tried this with Clang (it's just a warning to do so) and get almost the same code (not exactly the same because of the `#0` attributes, but close enough that I believe the differences are not causing this problem):

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind
define void @main() #0 {
entry:
  ret void
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't crash for me, so the culprit must be something else:

```
$ echo "define void @main() {entry: ret void}" | lli -
$
```

In any case, lli supports void main methods, as you can see in [`ExecutionEngine::runFunctionAsMain()`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ExecutionEngine_8cpp_source.html#l00434).

Comment: Thank you. I've tested with lli directly like you (instead of llvm-as then lli) and it still randomly crashes. I'm on Window 7 btw.

Comment: @Stringer have you managed to successfully run lli on anything? e.g. a clang-generated IR file? If you haven't, there must be a more fundamental issue involved - try asking a new question detailing the error and your build process. To verify it's not this void thing, you can also just change your main method to return some int and see if it behaves the same.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on a toy language that transpile to LLVM IR. So far so good because all my unit tests (68) were always returning i32 or i1 from the main. Build process is very simple: llvm-as then lli (I didn't know that lli could take IR string directly).

Comment: what is your version of lli and on which OS are you? Thanks. I will accept your answer because now I know it is legal to have a main returning void, I will try to rebuild lli in Debug to see what happens.

Comment: @Stringer my lli is from version 3.4.2, so roughly a year old. The code link I've provided is to the latest version, though.